# Combination of SQL Select statements

Tags: sql-server, ssms, inner-join, union

I am trying to take a "snapshot" of a state of some tables of our database. I have finished a few of them and I am currently working on the last, however for the last one I need to query two different tables.

So far have tried the following:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(Name) AS CRIT,
     branch
FROM
    (SELECT
         A.Name,
         A.branch,
         B.score,
         B.last_found
     FROM  
         TableA AS A
     INNER JOIN 
         TableB AS B ON A.Name = V.Name
     WHERE
         B.state <> 'DONE'
         AND DATEDIFF(day, B.last_found, GETDATE()) > 30
         AND CAST(B.score AS float) > 8) AS X
     GROUP BY
         branch
```

This will return me a portion of what I need:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/fGIgo.png)

I can slightly modify the code:

```
SELECT
     COUNT(Name) AS LOW,
     branch
FROM
    (SELECT
         A.Name,
         A.branch,
         B.score,
         B.last_found
     FROM   
         TableA AS A
     INNER JOIN 
         TableB AS B ON A.Name = V.Name
     WHERE
         B.state <> 'DONE'
         AND DATEDIFF(day, B.last_found, GETDATE()) > 30
         AND CAST(B.score AS float) < 4) AS X
     GROUP BY
         branch
```

To get the following:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/PILiX.png)

This is once again another portion of what I need. The final output should be a combination of the two above queries and should have 3 columns:

```
CRIT   LOW   Branch
```

Apologies if I am unclear and thank you for helping!!

Comment: FYI syntax like `DATEDIFF(day, B.last_found, GETDATE()) > 30` in the `WHERE` is *not* SARGable; rather than using `DATEDIFF` use `DATEADD` on `GETDATE()` **only** and check if the value of your column is *greater*/*less* than that expression.

Comment: Not to mention, as well, that `CAST(B>score as float) < 4` isn't valid syntax. *Presumably* you want `B.score` but why are you converting your column to a `float`? Surely that's not the right data type, and surely if you are storing numerical data you need to treat as a numerical value it's *stored* as a numerical data type? Right? That `CAST` isn't SARGable either.

Comment: On a side note: I would not `COUNT(name)`, because counting an expression is supposed to explicitly exclude nulls from the counting. The name cannot be null, because of the join, and maybe it is not nullable anyway. So, just count rows instead: `COUNT(*)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want conditional aggregation (`CASE` expression inside an aggregation function):

```
SELECT
   a.branch,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(b.score as float) > 8 THEN 1 END) AS crit,
   COUNT(CASE WHEN CAST(b.score as float) < 4 THEN 1 END) AS low
FROM tablea AS a
INNER JOIN tableb AS b ON b.name = a.name
WHERE b.state <> 'DONE'
AND DATEDIFF(day, b.last_found, GETDATE()) > 30
GROUP BY a.branch;
```

Comment: This could have rows that were not in either original (scores between 4 and 8), but hopefully close enough for the OP to figure out the rest. Personally, I'd also make the `DATEDIFF()` change suggested in the comments, so indexes on `b.last_found` can still be used.